# what is the best way to UV unrawp this model

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to unrwap this model but the bevel on the windows seem to make thing difficult.

any idea as for what to do?

[image: Image Link]

Also a picture of the entire model
[image: Image Link]

also in case its needed here is a link to the [Project File](https://we.tl/t-AT2ymcVngP)

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Apart from @moonboots answer, you could simply select All, use U > Clear Seams, then use U > Smart UV Project if you want an easy life! :^)

Answer (score 0):

Select the outer and inner faces, choose the front view and unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* option, scale the UVs on Y, the 2 UVs are overlapping but you can select each one in the 3D view and separate in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

As for the top and bottom ring, select them and either unwrap by default or choose *Follow Active Quads* if you want the faces to be orthogonal

Comment: hey sorry for the delay it took sometime before i was able to respond.
I did the "Cylinder Projection" But the result is completely warp. 

[Here is a screen shot](https://ibb.co/K9NJFDj)

Comment: choose the front view before unwrapping

Comment: i did choose the front view

Comment: The link has expired, could you please share the file again?